# Date-text is not converting to real date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had a bad time trying to import some excel data, then I found that there's a problem with a date field.
I thought the field is string-date text, but when I try to convert it to real-date, not all data convert well
 Here's a sample below

[image]

I tried to format cells, didn't work. Then tried
1- DATEVALUE and VALUE functions
2- ADD zero
3- DELIMITED text to columns
but nothing appears to work.
 What is this type of data?? and how to convert to real text?

appreciate your help.

Comment: You local settings are `mm/dd/yyyy` and the "dates" are coming in as `dd/mm/yyyy`.  Import them all as Text: format the column as text, then import.  Then use the Text to columns wizard and denote that the data is `d/m/y` on the third step.

Comment: I knew the issue after I tried to import, they are imported as null. Also, I tried converting to text, it doesn't change anything for the data.
This is how I received the data. and in any case, excel date columns are not relatable to machine date format. you can see that some data are convertible.

Comment: If you have TEXTJOIN: `=--TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A2,"mm/dd/yyyy"),"/","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{2,1,3}&"]"))`

Comment: @ScottCraner, I was mistaken. Because it was string-date, it took my machine formatting, so machine time format is relative. other data didn't convert because it can't put 13 or more as a month. Changed my formatting to dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!!
I needed to change my machine date format, I am not certain but here's what I think was the problem.
Because the data was a string-date not a real date, so excel took format of my machine which was `mm/dd/yyyy`.
 so for the first date `20/01/2000`, excel cannot put `20` as a `month` when I try to change format or run (text to column) or result in error in `DATEVLUE` and `VALUE`, so lots of dates didn't get formatted or resulted in error.
 On the other hand, the second date, `07/02/2002`, can be formatted and functions work well.
So, changing my machine format to dd/mm/yyyy solved the issue and data converted with simple Text to Column.

Big Credit for @ScottCraner

Answer (score 1):

In **B2** enter:

<strike>=IFERROR(VALUE(A2),DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),MID(A2,4,2),RIGHT(A2,2)))</strike>

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Fixed Formula and format:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(A2),DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If one has textjoin:

```
=--TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),"/","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{2,1,3}&"]"))
```

[image]

---

If not then parse the TEXT:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),4),MID(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),4,2),LEFT(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),2))
```

[image]